# Trigger autoinstall of android .apk after download from third party web server

Tags: android

I have an andorid .apk file which is downloaded from my web server. 
Everything works fine I can download and install however is there a way that I can auto trigger install of .apk once the file has been downloaded.

Thanks

Comment: When you are downloading it, shouldn't it auto detect the type and prompt you for an install?

Comment: I am using a Google Nexus S, it downloads fine but then the user needs to find the file in downloads and open it.

Comment: That sounds, in general, like a rather dangerous idea: "yes, I want to download and automatically install `dancing_hampsters_legit_really_not_harmful_at_all.apk` from an untrusted source". Do we need to repeat the (lack of) security model of Win98, this time on Android?

Comment: @Piskvor indeed security is an issue but I am working with a test group and the app. will eventually goto the market so until then I am allowing a select group to download and use it.

Comment: Are you downloading via a browser?

Comment: Yes indeed, using the builtin web browser on Nexus S. I get a toast stating download started, and in the notification bar I can see and access the finished download to successfully install. Surly the phone is recognising that it is .apk file. It cannot install silently anyway as it needs to confirm the permissions so why would auto install be blocked?

Comment: @milosh : if u have the answer pls share ...